# Proof verification: If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then $f$ must be continuous at infinitely many points in $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Nomenclature: Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ defined by $\{t_0,t_1,\dots,t_n\}$, with $a = t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n = b.$ Then we defined the upper and lower sums of $f$ on the partition $P$ as $U(f,P) := (\sup_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f)(t_i - t_{i-1}), L(f,P) := (\inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f)(t_i - t_{i-1})$, respectively. For brevity, we also define $M_i = \sup_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f$ and $m_i = \inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f$.

Let $f$ be integrable on $[a,b]$, and let $P = \{t_0,\dots,t_n\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ with $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < b - a$. We shall prove that for some $i$ we have $M_i - m_i < 1$.

Proof: Assume, to the contrary, that for every $i$ we have $M_i - m_i \ge 1$. Then, observe that $b - a > U(f,P) - L(f,P) = \sum M_i \Delta t_i - \sum m_i \Delta t_i = \sum (M_i - m_i)\Delta t_i \ge \sum \Delta t_i = b - a$, which is a contradiction.

Next we will show that there are numbers $a_1$ and $b_1$ with $a < a_1 < b_1 < b$ with $\sup f_{[a_1,b_1]} - \inf f_{[a_1,b_1]} < 1$.

Proof: Suppose $i \neq 1,n.$ Then choose $a_1 = t_{i-1}$ and $b_1 = t_i$ for the aforementioned $i$ above and we are done. Now suppose $i = 1$. Choose $b_1 = t_1$ and choose any $a_1$ which satisfies $a < a_1 < b_1$. It is clear that $\sup f_{[a_1,b_1]} \le \sup f_{[a,b_1]}$ and $\inf f_{[a_1,b_1]} \ge \inf f_{[a,b_1]}$ as $[a_1,b_1] \subset [a,b_1]$. Therefore, $1 > \sup f_{[a,b_1]} - \inf f_{[a,b_1]} \ge \sup f_{[a_1,b_1]} - \inf f_{[a_1,b_1]}$. If $i = n$, then choose $a_1 = t_{n-1}$ and let $b_1$ satisfy $a_1 < b_1 < t_n$. Then similarly, $\sup f_{[a_1,b_1]} \le \sup f_{[a_1,b]}$ and $\inf f_{[a_1,b_1]} \ge \inf f_{[a_1,b]}$, so $1 > \sup f_{[a_1,b]} - \inf f_{[a_1,b]} \ge \sup f_{[a_1,b_1]} - \inf f_{[a_1,b_1]}$, and so we are done.

Now define the interval $I_i := [a_i,b_i]$. We will prove that there are numbers $a_2, b_2$ with $a_1 < a_2 < b_2 < b_1$ with $\sup f_{I_2} - \inf f_{I_2} < \frac{1}{2}$.

Proof: Suppose, on the contrary, that for any $a_2,b_2$ satisfying $a_1 < a_2 < b_2 < b_1$, we have that $\sup f_{I_2} - \inf f_{I_2} \ge \frac{1}{2}$. Define the intervals let $X$ be the set of of $x$ satisfying $a_1 < x < \frac{a_1+b_1}{2}$ and let $Y$ be the set of $y$ satisfying $\frac{a_1+b_1}{2} \le y < b_1$. Choose $a_2, b_2 \in X$ with $a_2 < b_2$. Then $\sup f_X - \inf f_X \ge \frac{1}{2}$. Similarly, choose $a_2', b_2' \in Y$ with $a_2' < b_2'$. Then $\sup f_Y - \inf f_Y \ge \frac{1}{2}$. Since $X,Y$ are nonempty, we must have that $\sup I_1 = \sup(X+Y) = \sup X + \sup Y$ and similarly for $\inf$. Therefore, $1 > \sup f_{I_1} - \inf f_{I_1} \ge (\sup f_X + \sup f_Y) - (\inf f_X + \inf f_Y) \ge 1$, which is a contradiction.

We may repeat this argument by dividing the interval $(a_1,b_1)$ in two intervals (like above), then we divide the interval $(a_2,b_2)$ into three intervals, and so on until we divide $(a_n,b_n)$ into $n+1$ intervals. This process would look like so: let $A_1$ be the set of $x$ which satisfy $a_1 < x < \frac{b_{n} - a_{n}}{n} + a_{n}$, let $A_2$ be the set of $x$ which satisfy $\frac{b_{n} - a_{n}}{n} + a_{n} \le x < 2\frac{b_{n} - a_{n}}{n} + a_{n}$, and so on until $A_{n+1}$: $(n-1)\cdot\frac{b_{n} - a_{n}}{n} + a_{n} \le x < b_{n}$. We then choose $A_1 \ni a_{n1} \le b_{n1} \in A_1, A_2 \ni a_{n2} \le b_{n2} \in A_2$ and so on until $A_{n+1} \ni a_{n(n+1)} \le b_{n(n+1} \in A_{n+1}$. Now assume that $\sup f_{I_n} - \inf f_{I_n} \ge \frac{1}{n}$, and so $1 > \sup f_{I_1} - \inf f_{I_1} = \sum \sup f_{A_i} - \sum \inf f_{A_i} = \frac{1}{n} \cdot n = 1$, which is a contradiction.

Since $I_i = [a_i, b_i]$ and $a_n \le a_{n+1} \le b_{n+1} \le b_n$, we satisfy the requirements of the Nested Interval Theorem, which implies that there is an $x_0 \in I_k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}.$

Now set $\delta = \min(|a_k - x_0|,|b_k - x_0|)$, and let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given, and choose $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/k \le \varepsilon.$ Then notice that whenever $0 < |h| < \delta$, we have $|f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)| \le |\sup_{I_k} f - \inf_{I_k} f| < \frac{1}{k} \le \varepsilon$, since $x_0 + h$ is in an open interval containing $x_0$. In other words, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

To prove that $f$ is therefore integrable on infinitely many points, we note that $f$ being integrable on $[a,b]$ implies $f$ is integrable on $a \le c \le d \le b$. So by “pretending” that $a = t_0, b = t_0 + \varepsilon$, we may partition $[t_0,t_0 + \varepsilon]$ even further into $\{s_0,s_1,\dots,s_m\}$ and reapply our proof. We continue to do this for any subinterval, and as infinitely many subintervals exist, there will exist infinitely many points.

Comment: Can you add your definition of notations such as $U(f, P)$ and $L(f, P)$, $M_i$ and $m_i$, etc.?  Also, a “partition of $[a, b]$” is a family of disjoint subsets of $[a, b]$ whose union is $[a, b]$; I don’t think you meant to let $t_i$ be (arbitrary) subsets of $[a, b]$ here.

Comment: [Dirichlet's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) can be integrated but is nowhere continuous.  Your proof must be wrong because the claim is already wrong.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Dirichlet’s function is *not* Riemann integrable.  (It is Lebesgue integrable.)

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to include the definitions?

Comment: @L.F. I have added it to the top of the post.

Comment: Thanks for adding the definitions.  I can't make sense of this part: $\operatorname{sup}(I_1) = \operatorname{sup}(X+Y)=\operatorname{sup}(X) + \operatorname{sup}(Y)$.  Here $I_1 = X \cup Y$ by construction (not the [elementwise sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) $X + Y$), so what we should have is $\operatorname{sup}(I_1) = \operatorname{sup}(X \cup Y) = \max\{\operatorname{sup}(X), \operatorname{sup}(Y)\}$.  However, I think what you actually mean is $\operatorname{sup}(f_{I_1}) = \operatorname{sup}(f_X \cup f_Y) = \max\{\operatorname{sup}(f_X), \operatorname{sup}(f_Y)\}$

Comment: @L.F. I thought $\sup(X + Y) = \sup X + \sup Y$ (and similarly for $\inf$) is a basic proof of $\sup/\inf$, assuming $X,Y$ are not empty?

Comment: Yes, it is certainly true that $\sup(X + Y) = \sup X + \sup Y$ for non-empty $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}$ that are bounded above, but here we have $I_1 = X \cup Y \neq X + Y$.

Comment: That's true in the sense that $I_k = [a_k,b_k]$ but $X\cup Y = (a_k,b_k)$, but for $\sup/\inf,$ this doesn't affect it, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137712/discussion-between-l-f-and-polite-proofs).

Comment: A well-known generalisation of what you’re proving is that a function $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere (meaning its set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fallacy lies in

> Since $X$, $Y$ are nonempty, we must have that $\sup(I_1) = \sup(X + Y) = \sup X + \sup Y$ and similarly for $\inf$.

By construction, $I_1 = X \cup Y$, so
$\sup(I_1) = \sup(X \cup Y) = \max\{\sup(X), \sup(Y)\}$.
However, we can save this proof by simply reusing the first lemma to find subintervals.

A cleaned-up proof is shown as follows, using same the definitions and notations as the OP used.  The OP has clarified that the question refers to [Darboux integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral) (which is in fact equivalent to Riemann integration).

---

**Lemma 1**.  If the real function $f$ is Darboux integrable on the closed interval $[a, b]$ with $a < b$, and $\epsilon$ is a positive number, then there is a closed interval $I \subseteq (a, b)$ such that
$$
\sup f_I - \inf f_I < \epsilon.
$$

*Proof*.  By the definition of Darboux integration,
let $P = \langle t_0, t_1, t_2, \dotsc, t_n \rangle$ be a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval) of $[a, b]$ such that
$$
U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon (b - a).
$$
Suppose for the sake of contradiction that
$$
\sup f_{I_k} - \inf f_{I_k} \ge \epsilon
$$
for all subintervals $I_k = [t_{k-1}, t_k]$,
where $1 \le k \le n$.
Denote $\Delta t_k = t_k - t_{k-1}$.
Then,
$$ \begin{split}
U(f, P) - L(f, P)
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \sup(f_{I_k}) \Delta t_i
 - \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \inf(f_{I_k}) \Delta t_i \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (\sup(f_{I_k}) - \inf(f_{I_k})) \Delta t_i \\
&\ge \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \epsilon \Delta t_i = \epsilon(b - a),
\end{split} $$
which contradicts $U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon (b - a)$.
Therefore, there is some (closed) subinterval $I_k$
such that
$$
\sup f_{I_k} - \inf f_{I_k} < \epsilon.
$$

We are done if $1 < k < n$.
If $k = 1$, note that $I = [\frac{t_0 + t_1}{2}, t_1]$ satisfies
$$
\sup(f_I) - \inf(f_I)
\le \sup(f_{I_1}) - \inf(f_{I_1}) < \epsilon.
$$
Similarly, we choose $I = [t_{n-1}, \frac{t_{n-1} + t_n}{2}]$
if $k = n$.
In all cases, there is a closed interval $I \subseteq (a, b)$ such that
$$
\sup f_I - \inf f_I < \epsilon.
$$

---

**Lemma 2**.  If the real function $f$ is Darboux integrable on the closed interval $[a, b]$ with $a < b$, then $f$ is continuous at some $x_0 \in [a, b]$.

*Proof*.  The previous lemma gives a closed subinterval $I_1 \subseteq [a, b]$ such that $\sup(f_{I_1}) - \inf(f_{I_1}) < 1$.  But $f$ is also Darboux integrable on $I_1$, so the same lemma gives a closed subinterval $I_2 \subseteq I_1$ such that $\sup(f_{I_2}) - \inf(f_{I_2}) < \frac{1}{2}$.
This recursive process gives a sequence of closed intervals $I_1, I_2, I_3, \dotsc$ such that
$$
I_{k+1} \subseteq \operatorname{int} (I_k)
$$
and
$$
\sup(f_{I_k}) - \inf(f_{I_k}) < \frac{1}{k}
$$
for all $k \ge 1$.
Therefore, there is some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$x_0 \in \operatorname{int}(I_k)$ for all $k$
(where $\operatorname{int}(I_k)$ denotes the interior of $I_k$,
namely $\operatorname{int}([a, b]) = (a, b)$ when $a < b$).

We now show that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.
For any given $\epsilon > 0$,
choose $k$ such that $\frac{1}{k} < \epsilon$,
and choose $\delta > 0$ such that
$(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \subseteq I_k$.
Then, for all $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$,
$$
\lvert f(x) - f(x_0) \rvert
\le \sup(f_{I_k}) - \inf(f_{I_k}) < \frac{1}{k} < \epsilon.
$$
Therefore, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

---

**Corollary 3**.  If the real function $f$ is Darboux integrable on the closed interval $[a, b]$ with $a < b$, then $f$ is continuous at infinitely many $x \in [a, b]$.

*Proof*.  Let $x_k = a + \frac{1}{k} (b - a)$.
Apply the previous lemma to each of the subintervals
$[x_2, x_1], [x_3, x_2], [x_4, x_3], \dotsc$
to see that $f$ is continuous at (at least) one point in each of these (infinitely many) subintervals.

---

**Corollary 4** (bonus).  If the real function $f$ is Darboux integrable on the closed interval $[a, b]$ with $a < b$, then the set of points at which $f$ is continuous is dense in $[a, b]$.

The proof follows straightforwardly from the definition of a dense set.